# ordering of the items in my Linux Mint Panel messed up

Tags: linux-mint, main-desktop-panel

I have been using Linux Mint for about 2 months, so far so good. But today after I turned on my computer, I found that ordering of my items in the panel got messed up: normally I should have my date/time item on the right-most location, but now it wasn't. Items seems to be arranged randomly.

Why this will happen? Can I fix it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Mint is a great distro. Though not incredibly important, what version are you using?

If memory serves you can right click any panel option and either lock or unlock the item. If it isn't locked to the panel, it should be movable.